# Is there a way to permanently hide the "Chat" and "Invite a Friend" sections on left side panel of Gmail?

Tags: gmail

On the left hand column of Gmail I see my mailbox. Below the list of all my mailboxes, I get a section for "Chat" which lists my recent contacts, and below that, a section for "Invite a Friend".

I'd like to eliminate these. I can press '-' button to collapse them, but they remain visible and I think they reappear uncollapsed the next time you return to Gmail.

Is there a way to permanently delete these items, which I do not want to use, and do not want cluttering up my interface to Gmail?

Comment: Other solutions described here: http://nikunj-solutions.blogspot.fr/2011/10/remove-invite-friend-box-from-gmail.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way of doing this is through add-ons or extensions.
Take a look at [Better Gmail 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/better-gmail-2/) for firefox or [Better Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgdnblnolcinnndenjnollpiplgkbjcn) for Chrome.
These allow you to hide the chat and invite a friend blocks completely. They also can remove some other elements, and tweak some other ui elements as well.

Answer (score 3):

Click the ellipsis ("...") at the bottom left of the screen.  It toggles the display of "gadgets" like chat.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the GMail Settings or Labs, but you could install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) with [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/61985).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the chat box by clicking "turn off chat" at the bottom of the page.